# Docker throws error while building image (windows)

Tags: node.js, docker, discord, dockerfile

I tried building a docker image from the following dockerfile:

```
FROM node:10-alpine

RUN mkdir -p /app

WORKDIR /app
COPY * ./
RUN yarn install

CMD ["node", "/app/index.js"]
```

using:

```
$ docker build -t cloudy .
```

However, the cmd returns

```
[+] Building 12.3s (8/9)                                                                           docker:desktop-linux
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                  0.1s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                    0.0s
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                               0.1s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 155B                                                                               0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/node:10-alpine                                                  1.5s
 => [1/5] FROM docker.io/library/node:10-alpine@sha256:dc98dac24efd4254f75976c40bce46944697a110d06ce7fa47e7268470  0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                  1.4s
 => => transferring context: 829.22kB                                                                              1.4s
 => CACHED [2/5] RUN mkdir -p /app                                                                                 0.0s
 => CACHED [3/5] WORKDIR /app                                                                                      0.0s
 => ERROR [4/5] COPY * ./                                                                                          9.1s
------
 > [4/5] COPY * ./:
------
Dockerfile:6
--------------------
   4 |
   5 |     WORKDIR /app
   6 | >>> COPY * ./
   7 |     RUN yarn install
   8 |
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: cannot copy to non-directory: /var/lib/docker/overlay2/r3w2vmci1a20i21dql1ub8g5f/merged/app/discord.js
```

I've tried removing the github repo and git cloning it again, however this has not worked.
None of the .js files seem to have any issue either.

Comment: @Aracturat so line 6 becomes:
COPY * . . /
?

Comment: Try to replace it with `COPY . .`

Comment: Docker image seemed to build correctly, thanks